# SBT: sbt-native-packager update RPM symlinks

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to update a symlink on installation of a new version of RPM.

When an application installs the following happens

1. Installed under `/opt/app-<version>` (with folders lib,bin,etc in it)
2. Symlink `/opt/app/bin-<version>` is created for `/opt/app-<version>/bin`. (similarly for lib and etc)
3. Symlink `/opt/app/bin`  is created for `/opt/app/bin-version`

My build.sbt has the following setting:

```
settings = Seq(
   .....
  linuxPackageMappings <<= Seq(LinuxSymlink(s"""${rootAppPath.value}/bin-${(version in Universal).value}""", s"""../${appNameVersion.value}/bin"""),
    LinuxSymlink(s"""${rootAppPath.value}/bin""", s"""${rootAppPath.value}/bin-${(version in Universal).value}"""),
   .....
)
```

When I try to install a new version of the RPM, I get a rpm conflict error

`file /opt/app/bin from install of app-1.0.2-1.0.2-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package app-1.0.1-1.0.1-1.x86_64`

Comment: What does `rpm -ql <package>` or `rpm -qpl <package>.rpm` say about the `/opt/app/bin` path? What about `rpm -q --scripts <package>`/etc.?

Comment: @EtanReisner I had a bug in my plugin code which I fixed but now I get conflict errors. Updated the question with it.

Comment: Are you using `rpm -ivh` to install your new package? If so, don't. Use `rpm -Uvh` or `yum install` instead and see if that helps.